# Change div attribute value in Freemarker

Tags: html, css, freemarker

I have the below Freemarker code:

```
<#if variable1??>
    <div style="padding-left: 0;">
    ...
    </div>
<#else>
    <div>
    ...
    </div>
</#if>
```

I want to make padding left = 0 only if `variable1` is true. This logic works but would not be ideal when the div element has many sub elements.

How can I add something in the `<#if>` condition to make the padding left = 0?

Comment: Usually people use a class on the div instead of inline css. However I am still having trouble understanding the issue, is this in a macro or function or do you not know what the div will contain? or is your else statement the div with many elements? you can inline the freemarker anywhere you need to in the html

Comment: I know what the div will contain which is a huge piece of HTML code. So I want to align the page to left only if variable1 is true otherwise do not align to left. Can I put the freemarker <#if> condition inside the div tag?

Comment: Oh ok then yea just put the if statement in the div tag itself like the answer shows or you can define a variable with the string you need or else empty string then put the variable inside of the div in the html. It's a little bit cleaner but both does the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move if inside div element so you don't need to duplicate elements

```
<div  <#if variable1??>style="padding-left: 0;"<#else></#if>>
```